# Will FusionCharts work in the Force.com Platform?

Tags: fusioncharts, force.com

Will FusionCharts work in a java-based application running in the Force.com Platform?

Comment: FusionCharts is a client side component. Hence you would need to access your SF data and build XML as per FC data format and pass it to chart. You can use J2EE wrapper and various JavaScript API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FusionCharts will indeed work on the Force.com platform. Here's how to go about it.

You would need to use the Java Web Services Connector (WSC) for Force.com from here http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#Java. There are a few samples provided there to get you started with that WSC. You will need this wrapper to query Force.com externally.

Here is another introduction to using the WSC http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector.

Once you are comfortable with the above two, here is a short tutorial on how to use FusionCharts in J2EE - http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/Code/J2EE/JSP_GettingStarted.html.

Now the thing with Force.com's objects is that you would need to know the attributes of each object before you write the query for them (as in, knowing the column names of a database table). You can know about them easily from this AIR app provided by Force.com - ForceExplorer http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/ForceExplorer

You can form the queries using ForceExplorer, and copy them down in your Java code. You would then write the returned data into an XML. This tutorial from the FusionCharts documentation outlines it very well - http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/Code/J2EE/JSP_JS_URL.html